# update contact phone number

Tags: android

i want to update contact numbers but i can't here is my code

```
 Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_URI, Integer.parseInt(pID));
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
 values.put(People.Phones.TYPE, People.Phones.TYPE_MOBILE);
 values.put(People.Phones.NUMBER, "4084444444");
 values.put(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID,recNo);
 //getContentResolver().update(uri, values, null, null);
 int rows = getContentResolver().update(uri, values, null, null);
```

but the rows returned with value 0
if any one can help me . i need to solve it as soon as possible.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
String where =
   ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " +
   ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";

String[] whereParams = new String[] {
   raw_contact_id + "",
   ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
};

mContext
.getContentResolver()
.update(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, values, where, whereParams);
```

not null!